# Ember js RESTAdapter PUT request adds .json to the end

Tags: rest, ember.js, put

I've been trying to learn Ember and I have a question.

In my store I'am getting data from .json like below. I have tried without buildUrl function but cant load the json file, then found this solution on SO.

```
CocktailApp.Store = DS.Store.extend({
revision: 12,
adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    bulkCommit: false, 
    url: "http://localhost:8888",    
    buildURL: function(record, suffix) {
        var s = this._super(record, suffix);
        return s + ".json";
    }

})
});
```

Now comes my question: When I commit the chances (by pressing add to favs or remove from favs) RESTAdapter adds ".json" at the end of to PUT request. See the below code and screenshot

```
CocktailApp.CocktailController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
addToFav: function () {
this.set('fav',true);
this.get('store').commit();
},
removeFromFav: function () {
this.set('fav',false);
this.get('store').commit();
} 
});
```

[image]

I think thats why my PUT request can not be handled. But If I remove the builtURL function no json loaded at all. How can I resolve this problem? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the API endpoint url does not require `.json` at the end of it, then remove that line from your `buildURL` function. My guess is that the example code you got was consuming a ruby on rails api, or something similar.

remember, when you send a GET, PUT, POST, or DELETE to a url, that url needs to actually be a real endpoint. You can't just add extraneous stuff to it and have it still work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Kristian.
I already tried removing ".json" from buildURL but then, the real json file can not be read and shown as txt file on network tab.